# Variable in XSD Choice

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to create a `complexType` with a placeholder in a choice.

I have a series of `simpleTypes` that restrict `xs:string` based on a regular expression.

For example :

```
<!-- Define restricted string types -->
    <xs:simpleType name="nameA">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="(A\.\S+\.\S+\.a\d+\.v\d+|A\.Acme\.\S+\.a\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="nameB">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="B\.\S+\.\S+\.a\d+\.v\d+"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="nameC">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="(C\.\S+\.\S+\.a\d+\.v\d+|C\.Acme\.\S+\.a\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

I have a `complexType` in which I'd like to use a choice where depending on that type's usage, I either restrict one of the choices based on the simple types above

For example I have something like :

```
<xs:complexType name="baseType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="hash" type="aces:hashType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="uuid" type="dcml:UUIDType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="file" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="idString" type="VARIABLE TYPE HERE BASED ON USAGE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

That would get used like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="typeA">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="baseType">
                 <xs:sequence>
                     More elements here ... maybe some choices ... and attributes.
                 </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

The key is I'm trying to include `idString` in the choice but have `idString` type be variable.  I'm try to avoid repeating the `choice` over and over in each `typeA`, `typeB`, `typeC`, ... definition.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you want is impossible to specify in an XSD schema. You can substitute an element's type, but only based on the value of an attribute, with the `xs:alternative` feature. See https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/22.1/ug-editor/topics/xml-schema-diagram-alternative-properties.html